# unknown encoder libvo_aacenc

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

i am trying to convert a .mov file to an mp4 file using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i sample_iTunes.mov -c:v libx264 -vb 800k -c:a libvo_aacenc -ab 128k -ac 2 test.mp4
```

When i run this i get the following error:

> Unknown encoder 'libvo_aacenc'

So i attempted to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

However sadly im still getting the error.

Can anyone help me out here?

**aergistal answer**

Here are the log from the things youve asked me to check:

My operation system is `ubuntu 14.04`

output of `ffmpeg -codecs | grep aac`:

```
    ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
 DEA.L. aac                  AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
 D.A.L. aac_latm             AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Coding LATM syntax)
```

out put of:

```
avconv -codecs | grep aac
```

is:

```
    avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
DEA.L. aac                  AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (encoders: aac libvo_aacenc )
D.A.L. aac_latm             AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Coding LATM syntax)
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: @aergistal ive added the output of the two commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [libavcodec_extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libavcodec-extra) package in Ubuntu Trusty is a Libav additional codec library. Libav is a fork of FFmpeg.

You seem to have both installed on your system. If you compiled `ffmpeg` yourself you need to install `libvo-aacenc-dev` and re-configure ffmpeg with `--enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3`.

For `AAC` the recommended lib is `libfdk_aac`. See the [AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) and the [FFmpeg Compilation Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: i get the following error: 

marc@marc-X550JK:~$ --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3
--enable-libvo-aacenc: command not found

In other words i get command not found on --enable

Comment: No, you need to re-configure it with `./configure` then `make` etc. How did you install it in the first place?

Answer (score 13):

You can do `-c:a aac` to get `ffmpeg` to use its built-in `aac` encoder. The built-in encoder supposedly produces higher quality, so `libvo_aacenc` has been removed from precompiled binaries.

A command line that works for me is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i infile.mov -f mp4 -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -b:v 3800k -flags +loop -cmp chroma -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4300k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -bf 3 -coder 1 -me_method umh -me_range 16 -subq 7 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8+partb8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -c:a aac -b:a 125k -ar 48000 -ac 2 outfile.mp4
```

To get higher video quality, you can do `-b:v 8000k -maxrate 8500k` (or even higher if the source file has, like, `11000k`), and better audio with `-b:a 192k`

Comment: Exactly. Some light on this: The native FFmpeg AAC encoder has been stable since FFmpeg 3.0. If you were using libvo-aacenc or libaacplus, both of which have been dropped in FFmpeg 3.0, please consider switching to the native encoder (-c:a aac)

So swap the `-c:a libvo_aacenc` out for `-c:a aac`

Answer (score 0):

In your /home/yourname/.winff/ folder copy presets.xml to presets.xml.old, and edit presets.xml thus: replace every instance of -acodec libvo_aacenc with -acodec libfaac You can leave everything alse as-is. Save and exit. Run Winff and convert a video.